# Fault: Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist

Tags: python, soap, sabre, zeep

I am trying to use Python and the zeep module to access a Sabre SOAP API. I'm currently unable to create a Session because I keep getting this error:

```
Fault: Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist.
```

I have looked for a solution elsewhere on Stack Overflow and in the few examples it was because the developer was using the wrong action name. That doesn't seem to be the case here as the documentation says the Action is called "SessionCreateRQ" and I have been able to successfully create a Session (using SessionCreateRQ) in SoapUI.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep import xsd 
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken

s = Session()
s.proxies = {'http': "http://proxy:proxy@proxy:port",
             'https': "https://proxy:proxy@proxy:port"}



wsdl = 'http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/usg/SessionCreateRQ.wsdl'

client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=Transport(session=s))  

# Create the header XML structure
header = xsd.Element('MessageHeader', xsd.ComplexType([
                        xsd.Element('From', xsd.ComplexType([
                                        xsd.Element('PartyId', xsd.String())
                                        ])
                                    ),
                        xsd.Element('To', xsd.ComplexType([
                                        xsd.Element('PartyId', xsd.String())
                                        ])
                                    ),
                        xsd.Element('CPAId', xsd.String()),
                        xsd.Element('ConversationID', xsd.String()),
                        xsd.Element('Service', xsd.String()),
                        xsd.Element('Action', xsd.String()),
                        xsd.Element('MessageData', xsd.ComplexType([
                                xsd.Element('MessageID', xsd.String()),
                                xsd.Element('Timestamp', xsd.String()),
                                ])),
                        ])
                     )

# Apply the header values
header_value = header(
                    From={'PartyId': xsd.SkipValue},
                      To={'PartyId': xsd.SkipValue},
                      CPAId='IPCC',
                      ConversationID='ABC123@clientURL.com',
                      Service='Session',
                      Action='SessionCreateRQ',
                      MessageData={'MessageID': '1234',
                                   'Timestamp': '2018-10-22T16:30:00Z'}
                      )

# Call the method
client.service.SessionCreateRQ(POS='IPCC', _soapheaders=[header_value])
```

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

**Update:** I have updated my XML structure as suggested by Imran but I am still getting the "Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist:

```
header = xsd.Element('Header', xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element('MessageHeader', xsd.ComplexType([
                    xsd.Element('From', xsd.ComplexType([
                                    xsd.Element('PartyId', xsd.String())
                                    ])
                                ),
                    xsd.Element('To', xsd.ComplexType([
                                    xsd.Element('PartyId', xsd.String())
                                    ])
                                ),
                    xsd.Element('CPAId', xsd.String()),
                    xsd.Element('ConversationID', xsd.String()),
                    xsd.Element('Service', xsd.String()),
                    xsd.Element('Action', xsd.String()),
                    xsd.Element('MessageData', xsd.ComplexType([
                            xsd.Element('MessageID', xsd.String()),
                            xsd.Element('Timestamp', xsd.String()),
                            ])),
                    ])
                 ),
        xsd.Element('Security', xsd.ComplexType([
                        xsd.Element('UsernameToken', xsd.ComplexType([
                            xsd.Element('Username', xsd.String()),
                            xsd.Element('Password', xsd.String()),
                            xsd.Element('Organization', xsd.String()),
                            xsd.Element('Domain', xsd.String()),
                                                                    ]))
                                                ])
                  )

]))

# Apply the header values
header_values = header(MessageHeader={'From':{'PartyId': xsd.Nil},
                                      'To': {'PartyId': xsd.Nil},
                                      'CPAId': '1234',
                                      'ConversationID': '1234',
                                      'Service': 'SessionCreateRQ',
                                      'Action': 'SessionCreateRQ',
                                      'MessageData': {'MessageID': '1234',
                                                      'Timestamp': '2018-08-10T09:58:31Z'}},
                        Security={'UsernameToken': {'Username': 'username',
                                                    'Password': 'password',
                                                    'Organization': 'IPCC',
                                                    'Domain': 'AA'}})

client.service.SessionCreateRQ(POS='IPCC', _soapheaders=[header_value])
```

Answer (score 0):

Service element should match the value inside the Action element. Or keep the Service element empty

```xml
<eb:Service>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
<eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
```

OR

```xml
<eb:Service />
<eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
```

https://developer.sabre.com/resources/getting_started_with_sabre_apis/sabre_apis_101/how_to_guides/soap_apis_request_format

Also, to create a session you will need to pass on the credential under Header

```xml
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>USER_NAME</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
        <Organization>IPCC</Organization>
        <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Final xml generated

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId>app</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId>webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>4de1db4e-0e4c-48d3-8a73-4923ff8d2c5c</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service />
            <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>e0d3923a-e5d1-40f9-9629-3618c2f62a4d</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2018-11-29T17:07:41Z</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>USER_NAME</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
                <Organization>IPCC</Organization>
                <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <SessionCreateRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11">
            <POS>
                <Source PseudoCityCode="IPCC" />
            </POS>
        </SessionCreateRQ>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Imran. Unfortunately matching the Service and Action (or removing the Service) has not worked. I have updated my post with the credential information included in the header.

Comment: Can you share the final xml sent to the API. You may capture using Fiddler4.

I have added the xml generated at my end